# Animation property path problem

Tags: wpf, silverlight

This line works fine :-

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(ShiverDirection == Orientation.Horizontal ? "X" : "Y"));
```

where animation is :-

```
 private DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();

 private TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();

 ease.Springiness = 2;
 animation.EasingFunction = ease;
 Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, transform);
 Initialize();
 storyboard.Children.Add(animation);`
```

The code is broken but still it should give you a fair idea of what i am trying to do.

However when i just change TranslateTransform to RotateTransform it stops working :-

Can anybody tell me what is the Property path syntax for RotateTransform?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: How does someone reach over a 1000 rep and yet still not know how to format code in Stackoverflow ??

Comment: @AnthonyWJones  :- I was in hurry. I created this post in under 1 minute ;)

Comment: Fair enough, perhaps you should click the edit link and inspect my changes to see how much effort is involved in formatting the code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TranslateTransform has properties named X and Y, so your original code works. RotateTransform has properties Angle, CenterX, CenterY (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx)) so changing the transform type requires to change the properties name in the path.